# Convertir una instancia de Illuminate\Http\Request a una instancia de App\Http\Requests\ImagenRequest,

Tags: laravel, validación, laravel-8, requests

El error que muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador del Pokemon:

```
 */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            $pokemon= new Pokemon($request->all());
            $pokemon->save();
            $request['imageable_id'] = $pokemon->id;
            $isImageCreate=$this->createImage($request);
      }
        catch(\Exception $e){
              
        }
        return redirect('home');
    }

    private function createImage( $request){
        
         app(ImageController::class)->store($request);
        
    }
```

Código de la Clase Imagen

```
   public function store(ImagenRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request);
        $view = $request->input('view')? $request->input('view') : 'home';
        $file = $this->getDataFromImage($request);
        
        //Upload img and save img
        $isUploaded = $this->isUploadImageToStorage($file);
        
        ($isUploaded) && $this->saveImageInDataBase($file);
        
        return redirect($view);
    }
```

**Contexto: Lo que quiero es pasar los datos de tipo request a tipo ImagenRequest**  para que a la hora de llegar los datos a la función store del controlador de imágenes no salte un error y el código se ejecute. No se si esto es posible de realizar. Alguna recomendación de como realizarlo. Toda respuesta es bienvenida.

Código de ImagenRequest, como pueden ver se trata de una validación:

```
class ImagenRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
      
        return [
            'avatar'=>'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:4096',
            'imageable_type'=>'required|in:user, pokemon',
            
            'imageable_id'=>[ 'required', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
    
               if (!(DB::table('users')->where('id','=', $value)->exists()
                   || 
                   DB::table('pokemon')->where('id','=', $value)->exists())
                  )
                    {
                    return $fail("Este $attribute no es valido.");
                    }
                }
           ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImagenRequest` extiende de `FormRequest` que a su vez extiende de `Request`, así que puedes crear una instancia mediante el método [createFrom](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/95b732f30adba8f02fca47e4af625e221691cc81/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L415).

```
 public function store(Request $request)  {

     $pokemon= new Pokemon($request->all());
     $pokemon->save();
     $imagenRequest = ImagenRequest::createFrom($request)
                        ->merge(['imageable_id'=>$pokemon->id]);
     $isImageCreate=$this->createImage($imagenRequest);
     return redirect('home');
 }
```

Aunque según yo más que redirigir al home debiera mostrar el resultado de la inserción.

No estoy seguro si un FormRequest invocado internamente pasa por la etapa de validación. Yo diría que te tocará ejecutar la validación a mano via

```
private function createImage(ImagenRequest $request){
   $this->validate($request,$request->rules());
   app(ImageController::class)->store($request);
}
```